# 40 million tweets from 200k users

Tags: python, mysql, performance

```
mysql> select count(username) from users where no_tweets  > 50;
+-----------------+
| count(username) |
+-----------------+
|          282366 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (5.41 sec)

mysql> select sum(no_tweets) from users where no_tweets > 50;
+----------------+
| sum(no_tweets) |
+----------------+
|       38569853 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (1.75 sec)
```

I have that many users, who have collectively tweeted that many tweets. My aim is to store them in a file and then find out what a user generally tweets about (for starters, my aim is to run vanilla LDA and see if it works well on short documents), but the problem is that I ran the python code like an hour back and it has still not finished even 2% of users. I have posted the python code below.

```
'''
The plan is : Find out all users  from the users database who have more than 50 tweets
Create a file for them in the directory passed as an argument with the same name as the username and write all the tweets in them 
'''
def fifty(cursor):
    ''' Find all users and return , all of them having more than 50 tweets'''
    cursor.execute("select username from users where no_tweets>50")
    return cursor.fetchall()

def connect():
    ''' Cursor for mySQLdb'''
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="rohit",passwd="passwd",db="Twitter")
    return conn.cursor()

def tweets(cursor,name):
    ''' All tweets by a given user'''
    cursor.execute("select tweets from tweets where username='"+name+"'")
    return cursor.fetchall()
import sys,os,MySQLdb
directory = sys.argv[1] #Directory to write the user files
cursor = connect()
rows = fifty(cursor) #Find all users who have more than 50 tweets

for i in rows:#For all users
    data = open(os.path.join(directory,i[0]),'w') #Open a file same as their name
    allTweets = tweets(cursor,i[0]) #Find all tweets by them
    for j in allTweets:
        data.write(j[0]+"\n") #Write them 
    data.close()
```

The problem is that the code is running too slow and at this rate, it will take more than a day for it to finish writing all files. So some way that would make it faster would be great. So yeah, that is the question.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Did not realize that I had not put the question in there . Apologies. Made the necessary changes

Comment: This really isn't a "just go and fix my code for me" place. If you just want someone to go do the work for you you should hire a dev.

Comment: If I had written no code at all and asked for help  from someone to literally write the code , that would have made sense.  I thought  SO is a place where mistakes by people who are learning , like me,  are corrected by those who can correct them.

Comment: My gut feeling is that performance is slow due to I/O.  That can't be avoided, but perhaps you could look into the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 8):

Yikes, you're running almost 3,000,000 individual queries.  If you could do 4 a second (and you probably cannot) that is *still* a day!

How about just

```
select username, tweets from tweets order by username
```

Then of course you have to do some fancy footwork to switch from one file to the next when the user changes.

It should only take a few hours to run.

Comment: I guess I will have to make necessary change so that I select only those users who have more than 50 tweets in the other table .

Comment: `select t.username, tweets from tweets t, (select username from tweets group by username having count(*) > 50) e where e.username = t.username order by t.username` -- but if you think *most* people have more than 50 (seems likely, since the average is 500), you might be better off just creating the files for everybody and deleting the small ones later.

Comment: I thought of the creating all files earlier. But , only 3% of users have more than 50 tweets ~ ( 282366 / 6161529  ). So had to chuck that. Thanks ! Thanks again !

Comment: And I actually have two tables. One is (username,tweets) and other is (username,no_tweets) . I stored them separately as username would be a primary key in the 2nd table. Plus would help for future reference

Comment: mysql> select t.tweets tweets,u.username username from tweets t,users u where t.username=u.username and u.no_tweets > 50 order by t.username;
Is this one correct ?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Try it out.

Comment: When I ran it from cursor.execute , it  gave an error :( Incorrect key for the table it seems :(

Comment: And this happened after 4 hours of running, so I suspect something else went wrong altogether

Comment: Well, what was the error?

Comment: The error was InternalError: (126, "Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/mysql.ms5v75/#sql_6cd_1.MYI'; try to repair it") <-- I think my root ran outta memory . I have asked MySQL to store everything on my /home directory , but , this query, I ran using IPython. So I think it was writing everything into that . Could that be the prob ?

Comment: [Out of file space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090073/mysql-incorrect-key-file-for-tmp-table-when-making-multiple-joins).  You can't be shocked about that.

Comment: The weird part is that I have given /home/crazyabtliv/mysql as my defacto path. Then why did MySQLdb try and store things somewhere else  :(

Answer (score 5):

On the database side of things, make sure you have an index on the `username` field of the tweets table, if you don't MySQL will perform a full disk read on each query, taking minutes at a time (in a good scenario).

If you're using a transactional database, using transactions (that is, closing them) is a good idea. Assuming python2.6 (or do an `from __future__ import with_statement` for 2.5), this is almost trivially easy.

Also, the username in the where should be escaped so that unfortunate twitterhandles don't mess up your query, or your database:

```
import os
import operator
import sys
import MySQLdb

def Connect():
  return MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='rohit', passwd='bloodline', db='Twitter')

def FiftyPlus(conn):
  with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE no_tweets > 50')
    return map(operator.itemgetter(0), cursor.fetchall())


def Tweets(conn, name):
  with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT tweets FROM tweets WHERE username = %s', (name,))
    return map(operator.itemgetter(0), cursor.fetchall())


def WriteUserTweets(base_dir, username, tweets):
  with file(os.path.join(base_dir, username), 'w') as user_tweet_log:
    for tweet in tweets:
      user_tweet_log.write(tweet + '\n')


def main():
  root_dir = sys.argv[1]
  conn = Connect()
  for user in FiftyPlus(conn):
    tweets = Tweets(conn, user)
    WriteUserTweets(root_dir, user, tweets)
```

Comment: I have  an index on username.  Thanks !  I will need to dig up something on transactional databases :( Will do

Comment: Also, depending on your filesystem, you'll want to find a way to store the files in more than one directory. All flavors of ext (linux) and windows filesystems (and I've no reason to believe it'll be better on a Mac) start to give horrible performance once a directory accumulates over 50,000 files.

Comment: Sigh .  Okay :)  Will do that then.

Comment: I rate that question 2-1-1.  Two wins: proper handling of the username (although not required at all in my, ahem, superior solution, it's still a good idea in the abstract), and breaking up the files into subdirectories; one miss: username was already indexed; and one mistake: using a transaction in an *unchanging* database only slows things down.

Answer (score 1):

Am i missing something here or why don't you do it in one simple query and let MySQL write the file?

```
SELECT 
u.username,
t.tweets
INTO OUTFILE 'plus50tweets.txt'
FROM
tweets t
INNER JOIN users u ON u.username=t.username
WHERE u.no_tweets > 50
ORDER BY u.username
```

(untested. see also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

That will still be rather slow without any indexing and keys; so use users.username as your primary key, and add an index on users.no_tweets. Add another (non-primary) key on tweets.username. If that doesn't help, set the foreign keys in tbl tweets to the users table.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a database for this.  Use files.

A single file with one tweet per line showing User Name, Tweet Text and whatever other information you have.

You need to sort the file by user.  Use the OS-level `sort` program, don't write your own.

Once the tweets are sorted by user, you simply read and count.

```
def group_by_user( iterable ):
    tweet_iter= iter(iterable)
    first= next(tweet_iter)
    group= [ first ]
    user= first.user
    for tweet in tweet_iter:
        if tweet.user != user:
            yield user, group
            user= tweet.user
            group = []
         group.append(tweet)
    yield user, group

Tweet = namedtuple( 'Tweet', ['user','text',etc.] )

def make_named_tuples( raw_tweets ):
    for tweet in raw_tweets:
        yield Tweet( tweet.split('\t') ) # or whatever

with open( some_file ) as source:
    for user, group in group_by_user( iterable )
        if len(group) > 50: 
            # Open and write to a file.
```

This does not involve the **huge** overheads of a database.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this code is likely I/O bound. Let's bring down the time it takes to perform all the tweets queries:

### Improving read performance: parallel queries

Assuming the hardware running your MySQL database is capable, you can greatly improve the performance of the overall process by running multiple queries in parallel. I'm partial to [gevent](http://gevent.org) for this sort of thing, but the `threading` module from the Python standard lib should be more than sufficient. What we want to do is have multiple queries being performed at once, so that we are spending less time overall waiting for responses. To do this we take this code:

```
for i in rows:#For all users
    data = open(os.path.join(directory,i[0]),'w') #Open a file same as their name
    allTweets = tweets(cursor,i[0]) #Find all tweets by them
    for j in allTweets:
        data.write(j[0]+"\n") #Write them 
    data.close()
```

And instead do something like this:

```
def save_tweets(users):
    ''' For each username in the queue, retrieve all of their tweets and save them to disk '''  
    cursor = connect()
    while True:
        username = users.get()
        with open(os.path.join(directory, username),'w') as output:
            for tweet in tweets(cursor, username):
                output.write(row[0] + '\n')
        users.task_done()

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
user_queue = Queue()
# Perform at most 10 queries at the same time.
max_connections = 10
for i in max_connections:
    t = Thread(target=save_tweets, args=(user_queue,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for row in rows:#For all users
    user_queue.put(row[0])
user_queue.join() # Wait for all tasks to be completed
```

Now, somebody is bound to point out that you should use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of `threading`, and they may be right. If you find that the Python process for this script (**not** MySQL) is using 100% of the CPU time on one core, then you should consider using multiprocessing. Luckily it's a near drop-in replacement for the `threading` module, so the code will need very little change to adapt to it. Either way, this should get you into the position where you're pushing your database server to it's limits.

### Alternative, use the powers of SQL

Another approache that might be fun to try is using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function (found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)) to perform all of the work in a single query like so:

```
SELECT user, GROUP_CONCAT(tweet SEPARATOR '\n') as tweet_data, count(*) as tweet_count
FROM tweets WHERE tweet_count > 50
GROUP BY user;
```

However, given the amount of data you're dealing with, you'll probably just make your database server start swapping data in and out of memory and drive it's performance into the ground. (Unless your server happens to have +8GB of RAM, which according to Makotos estimates should be enough to hold the entire working set in memory)

Answer (score -3):

You want better performance?

if you want really better performance you should try to use some of the compiled code languages (like C). Because interpreted language takes much more time.

For example, if you take a simple loop, you will notice the difference

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

```
for(i = 0; i < 1500000; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < 10000; j++){

   }
}
```

It's like 50x faster with C comparing to Python.

Comment: That won't help *at all*.  The OP's post is I/O-bound, not CPU-bound.  Changing the language won't change that.

Comment: Yes it does help, compiled language are much better to perform these tasks that takes a lot of time and computer consuming.

Comment: There's only so many bits you can slam onto hardware at a time.  No programming language can change that.

Comment: @Makoto -- often, there are tricks you can do to reduce the amount of work to be done.  The expensive part of a query is often making the query itself: creating it, parsing it, optimizing it.  The OP had a quarter-million unnecessary queries he can get rid of.

Comment: @Malvolio:  Yes, the query is expensive, and that can be optimized.  That still doesn't change the ~40 million tweets that are being written to disk on the basis of an individual's name.  If we assume that each tweet is on average 80 characters long, then that's on the order of 6GB worth of data being written to disk.

Comment: My laptop can save 6GB to disk in 15 seconds.  It's not that.